# How to pause music(mp3) using Tone.player of Tone.js?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, p5.js, pause, tone.js

I'm new to tone.js and I just want a simple pause button. I know that there is a stop() and start() but it's not a pause and when to start again the music just go to the beginning of the song.

I use tone.js because I want to manipulate the music and do some synthesizing sound. I also use p5.js but somehow the pause dose not work. It throws an error saying "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. So I want to use tone.js but just have to figure out how to pause the music. Thanks.

Here's the code

```js
var player = new Tone.Player("data/audio/singingbird_audio.mp3").toMaster();
var whale = new Tone.Player("data/audio/whale.mp3").toMaster();
whale.autostart = false;
whale.volume.value = -10;
player.autostart = false;
player.volume.value = 5;
player.stop();

button = createButton('Play Bird');
button.position(20, 200);
button.mousePressed(birdSwitch);

function birdSwitch() {
    if (player.state == "started") {
        player.stop();
        whale.stop();
    } else if (player.state == "stopped") {
        player.start();
        whale.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why Johannes is being such a buzz kill. There's absolutely no reason NOT to use Tone.js. It's a really cool library.

Besides, the ACTUAL solution is easier than the solution Johaness so unhelpfully came up with.

**SOLUTION**

Literally all you need to do is sync the Player objects to the Tone.Transport and then you can play/pause/stop all day long by controlling the Transport instead of the players

Try modifying your code to look like this

```
var player = new Tone.Player("data/audio/singingbird_audio.mp3").toMaster();
var whale = new Tone.Player("data/audio/whale.mp3").toMaster();

// sync the Players to the Transport like this
player.sync().start(0);
whale.sync().start(0);

whale.volume.value = -10;
player.volume.value = 5;

button = createButton('Play Bird');
button.position(20, 200);
button.mousePressed(birdSwitch);

function birdSwitch() {
    if (player.state == "started") {
        // Use the Tone.Transport to pause audio
        Tone.Transport.pause();
    } else if (player.state == "stopped") {
        // Use the Tone.Transport to start again
        Tone.Transport.start();
    }
}
```

**ADDITIONAL IDEAS**

If you want to make the UI for your program even easier, you may also want to consider using the "tonejs-ui.js" library, which has a great Play/Pause/Stop button in it.

Just include the link to the "tonejs-ui.js" library  in your `<head>` and then you can use the `<tone-play-toggle>` element in your HTML and add an event listener to it that triggers the Transport start/pause.

Here's an example of the code you'd need to add to your HTML file and the event listener to add to your javascript instead of the logic you're using for your own button. Hopefully this makes sense.

```
<head>
   <!-- The tonejs-ui.js CDN link     -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/@tonejs/ui@0.0.8/build/tonejs-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

   <tone-content>
      <tone-play-toggle></tone-play-toggle>
   </tone-content>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      document.querySelector("tone-play-toggle").addEventListener("play", (e) => {

         const playing = e.detail;

         if (playing){
            Tone.Transport.start();
         } else {
            Tone.Transport.pause();
         }
      });

   </script>
</body>
```

Comment: It makes so much sense, @EfficiencyJunky ! Thank you for taking your time explaining this and tell me that there's tonejs-ui.js exited in this world. Hahah. I will try this solution. Currently, because I can't solve the issue before your comment, I turn to old p5.js version and use it to pause the mp3. With your advice, I think my project could be further developed. Thank you !!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it helped you out! The Tone.js library is truly amazing so I'm happy you are using it. One thing to mention about the tonejs-ui.js library, they say on the Tone.js website that they only really made it for demo purposes, so it may not work for every case you need to use it in, but for basic stuff it's great! Happy coding!

Comment: Just a note: toMaster() has been renamed to .toDestination() in more recent tone.js versions - other than that, this solution works great!

Comment: @EfficiencyJunky Any chance if you have time ofc, of providing an updated answer for v.v14.7.77 Your example does not work anymore, and I'm struggling to get Tone.Js do start and pause, it's not an easy lib with simple api to get working.

Answer (score -1):

Tone.js is a bit of a overkill to just play an mp3 file.

Why not just using the `<audio>`-Tag?
That way you can directly play and pause it.

```html
<button id="pause">Play/Pause</button>
<audio
  id="audioNode"
  src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-7.mp3"
  controls
></audio>
```

```js
const audio = document.getElementById("audioNode");

document.getElementById("pause").addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
  } else {
    audio.pause();
  }
});
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-wiles-ehy8y

In Tonejs a player is just a wrapper around an audio buffer. Play, pausing, etc. is done by syncing the players to the Transport class and use Transports play, pause, stop functionalities. Which then propagates to the players. But since the Transport has an internal timeline I don't think that this is what you need, since you would have to reset the Transport to the correct position, etc.

I guess in the end it's way more convenient for you to just fall back to the simpler solution.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the suggestion! I'll try your way. But like I've mentioned, I used Tone.js because other parts of the program are about synthesizing the audio on the web.